# Work locally without precompiling assets after each change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a good way to work so I dont have to precompile my assets locally everytime I make a change in my css/js files? i.e. just precompiling before pushing?

Currently I dont see the changes in my local server until they've been precompiled..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

`rake assets:clean`

(possibly with `bundle exec` in front of it). This will clear the local cache, and allow you to make changes on the fly in the development environment. Unless you explicitly run this (after precompiling and pushing your changes) it will keep going to the compiled assets, as you've noticed.